# How to implement google notifiers like alerts

Tags: cocoa

I am very fond of this feature of google notifiers:

If a new mail comes in gmail, it shows its alert on a semi-transparent borderless window on top right side of my mac, which fads away after some time.

Can anyone suggest me how can I show alert messages with similar appearance and animation in a sample application?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Growl](http://growl.info/) framework.